# Is there any chance I can recover at least some files - SSD, removed partition that used to house data. Haven't overwritten data location

Tags: 20.04, data-recovery

Ohh crap, well I backed up my files and went to install Pop!_OS, formatted my drive, and repartitioned everything, well, I'm an IDIOT and left my encryption key for the backup... on Ubuntu, which I just formatted... great.

So, I have repartitioned + formatted the drive, however I am almost 100% certain that I have not overwritten the location of my data. Is there any possible way to recover this, ideally without the use of a secondary drive?

Comment: Sorry to hear about that.  Yikes I have done that too.  No way to recover unless you have the key.  The files are all there but encrypted.

Comment: Ah well, worth a try. Cheers!